# custom post archive URL is wrong

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I recently found out that I could use the `with-front=>false` argument in `register_post_type()`. So I went and changed my custom post type slugs and did a `flush_rewrite_rules()`.  Now 2 of my custom post types are using the desired URLs and 2 are not. The only difference between the 2 that work and the others, is that they also have custom taxonomies. Here is the code from my `functions.php` file. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
add_action('init','ASH_addtaxonomies');
add_action('init','ASH_addposttypes');

function ASH_addtaxonomies(){
    register_taxonomy('ash_weave_structure', null,
                      array('labels'=>array('name'=>'Weave Structures',
                                            'singular_name'=>'Structure'),
                            'public'=>true,
                            'hierarchical'=>true,
                            'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'samples_weaving/structures', 'with-front'=>false),
                            'query_var'=>true
                      )
    );
    register_taxonomy('ash_weave_technique', null,
                    array(  'labels'=>array(    'name'=>'Weaving Techniques',
                                                'singular_name'=>'Technique'),
                            'public'=>true,
                            'hierarchical'=>false,
                            'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'samples_weaving/techniques', 'with-front'=>false),
                            'query_var'=>true
                    )
    );  
    register_taxonomy('ash_equip_cats', 'ash_equipment',
                    array(  'labels'=>array(    'name'=>'Equipment Categories',
                                                'singular_name'=>'Equipment Category'),
                            'public'=>true,
                            'hierarchical'=>true,
                            'show_ui'=>true,
                            'show_in_nav_menus'=>true,
                            'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'equipment/category', 'with_front'=>false),
                            'query_var'=>true
                    )
    );
}

function ASH_addposttypes(){

    //good archive url: http://example.com/samples_weaving/
    register_post_type('ash_weaving',
                        array(
                          'description' => 'Picture, draft and technical details of a weaving sample',
                          'public' => true,
                          'show_ui' => true,
                          'show_in_menu' => true,
                          'menu_position'=>5,
                          'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'samples_weaving', 'with_front'=>false),
                          'query_var' => true,
                          'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','ash_weave_structure','ash_weave_technique'),
                          'has_archive'=>true,
                          'supports' => array(  'title',
                                                'editor',
                                                'excerpt',
                                                'comments',
                                                'revisions',
                                                'thumbnail',
                                                'author',
                                                'page-attributes'),
                          'labels' => array ( 'name'=>__('Weaving Samples'),
                                              'singular_name'=>__('Weaving Sample')
                                              )
                        )
                    );
    //bad archive url: http://example.com/archives/samples_spinning/
    register_post_type('ash_spinning',
                        array(
                          'description' => 'Picture and technical details of a spinning sample',
                          'public' => true,
                          'show_ui' => true,
                          'show_in_menu' => true,
                          'menu_position'=>5,
                          'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'samples_spinning', 'with-front'=>false),
                          'query_var' => true,
                          'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag'),
                          'has_archive'=>true,
                          'supports' => array(  'title',
                                                'editor',
                                                'excerpt',
                                                'comments',
                                                'revisions',
                                                'thumbnail',
                                                'author',
                                                'page-attributes'),
                          'labels' => array ( 'name'=>__('Spinning Samples'),
                                              'singular_name'=>__('Spinning Sample')
                                              )
                    )
    );

    //bad archive url: http://example.com/archives/samples_dyeing/  
    register_post_type('ash_dyeing',
                        array(
                          'description' => 'Picture and technical details of a dyeing sample',
                          'public' => true,
                          'show_ui' => true,
                          'show_in_menu' => true,
                          'menu_position'=>5,
                          'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'samples_dyeing','with-front'=>false),
                          'query_var' => true,
                          'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag'),
                          'has_archive'=>true,
                          'supports' => array(  'title',
                                                'editor',
                                                'excerpt',
                                                'comments',
                                                'revisions',
                                                'thumbnail',
                                                'author',
                                                'page-attributes'),
                          'labels' => array ( 'name'=>__('Dyeing Samples'),
                                              'singular_name'=>__('Dyeing Sample')
                                              )
                        )
    );

    //good archive url: http://example.com/equipment/
register_post_type('ash_equipment',
                        array(
                          'description' => 'Weaving and spinning equipment that ASH makes available to members',
                          'public' => true,
                          'show_ui' => true,
                          'show_in_menu' => true,
                          'menu_position'=>5,
                          'rewrite'=>array('slug'=>'equipment','with_front'=>false),
                          'query_var' => true,
                          'taxonomies'=>array('post_tag','ash_equip_cats'),
                          'has_archive'=>true,
                          'supports' => array(  'title',
                                                'excerpt',
                                                'thumbnail',
                                                'page-attributes'),
                          'labels' => array ( 'name'=>__('Equipment'),
                                              'singular_name'=>__('Equipment')
                                              )
                        )
        );
}
```

Comment: In your registers, it's `with_front`, you're using `with-front` in some of them.

Comment: @Shane: Argh! Thank you so much. Why I couldn't see that I don't know.

Comment: Wasn't sure if that was the fix, i'll post it as an answer as to clear the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the register functions, in `rewrite`, you have to change `with-front` to `with_front`.